# How to resolve Supabase Cronjob Fatal Error

Tags: postgresql, cron, supabase

In Supabase, after an update to a column, I want to update the same column again only once after 5 minutes. To do this, I'm using a Function Trigger that calls a database function that uses a cronjob for the update. Here's the function trigger for an "After Update" event on the table:

```
  declare
    updated_inventory_order jsonb;
    max_delivery_est INTEGER := 5;
    cronjob_scheduled BOOLEAN;
    scheduled_job_name TEXT;
  begin   
    scheduled_job_name := 'fulfill_job';
   
     -- check if job has been scheduled
     SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM cron.job
        WHERE jobname = scheduled_job_name
     ) INTO cronjob_scheduled;

     IF cronjob_scheduled = true then 
       return new;
     END IF;

     -- ok, get order for which we want to perform an update schedule
     select row_to_json(inventory_order.*) 
     into updated_inventory_order
     from inventory_order
     where inventory_order_id = new.inventory_order_id;
     
     -- bail out if unfulfillment_status is not fulfilling
     if updated_inventory_order->>'fulfillment_status' <> 'fulfilling' then 
        return new;
      end if;

   -- schedule cronjob
     PERFORM cron.schedule(
      scheduled_job_name,
      format('*/%s * * * *', max_delivery_est),
      format('SELECT update_fulfillment_status2(%L, %L)', 'fulfilled', new.inventory_order_id)
     );

     --RAISE NOTICE 'Day: %, Hour: %, Minute: %', day, hour, minute;
     return new;
end;
```

Here's the update function:

```
 declare
    scheduled_job_name TEXT;
    unscheduled BOOLEAN;
begin
  scheduled_job_name :=  'fulfill_job';

  -- note: status and inv_order_id are passed into this function as arguments
  update public.inventory_order set 
  fulfillment_status = status
  where inventory_order.inventory_order_id = inv_order_id;
  SELECT cron.unschedule(scheduled_job_name) into unscheduled;
end;
```

While both the scheduling and unscheduling statements work, I'm getting this error: "Fatal Error the database system is in recovery mode"
What I'm I doing wrong and how can I fix it.
This cronjob runs every 5mins but I want it run just once after 5mins so that I don't have to unschedule it. Also how do I print(RAISE NOTICE) statements in a Supabase function.